# Custom label setup - font,color,size not being used?

Tags: core-plot

From the Plot Gallery sample - LabelingPolicyDemo.m, it uses a label policy of none, and sets each label up using the same style as the axis title:

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorTickLineStyle = [axisLineStyle mutableCopy];
majorTickLineStyle.lineWidth = 3.0;
majorTickLineStyle.lineCap   = kCGLineCapRound;

CPTMutableLineStyle *minorTickLineStyle = [axisLineStyle mutableCopy];
minorTickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
minorTickLineStyle.lineCap   = kCGLineCapRound;

// Text styles
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
axisTitleTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTitleTextStyle.color = [CPTColor redColor]; // differs from sample

// Tick locations
CPTNumberSet *majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithObjects:@0, @30, @50, @85, @100, nil];

CPTMutableNumberSet *minorTickLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
for ( NSUInteger loc = 0; loc <= 100; loc += 10 ) {
    [minorTickLocations addObject:@(loc)];
}

// Axes
// CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone
CPTXYAxis *axisNone = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
axisNone.plotSpace          = graph.defaultPlotSpace;
axisNone.labelingPolicy     = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axisNone.orthogonalPosition = @1.0;
axisNone.tickDirection      = CPTSignNone;
axisNone.axisLineStyle      = axisLineStyle;
axisNone.majorTickLength    = majorTickLength;
axisNone.majorTickLineStyle = majorTickLineStyle;
axisNone.minorTickLength    = minorTickLength;
axisNone.minorTickLineStyle = minorTickLineStyle;
axisNone.title              = @"CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone";
axisNone.titleTextStyle     = axisTitleTextStyle;
axisNone.titleOffset        = titleOffset;
axisNone.majorTickLocations = majorTickLocations;
axisNone.minorTickLocations = minorTickLocations;

CPTMutableAxisLabelSet *newAxisLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label %lu", (unsigned long)i]
                                                      textStyle:axisNone.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = @(i * 20);
    newLabel.offset       = axisNone.labelOffset + axisNone.majorTickLength / CPTFloat(2.0);

    [newAxisLabels addObject:newLabel];
}
axisNone.axisLabels = newAxisLabels;
```

but the resulting axis label and title should match which they don't - neither size, color or font?  The label text style appears constant.

See [Axis Labeling Policies](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8QzZhjxD4brMzhfUE80cElGQkE) sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question sets the red text style to the `titleTextStyle` and uses the `labelTextStyle` when creating axis labels. These text styles are independent although you can use the same style for both if you want.

Comment: Ah, so each axis has a title *and* a label text style, thanks!